# L2 point ephemeris (celestial mechanics)

Tags: python, astropy, astronomy

I'm a master student and I am trying to get the L2 ephemeris for some calculations in my master's project. It was kinda hard to find a file with the L2 ephemeris, but once I found it, I tried the next syntax.

```
from jplephem.spk import SPK
kernel = SPK.open('L2_de431.bsp')
position = kernel[3,392].compute(2457061.5)
```

but I'm getting an exception: "Only SPK data types 2 and 3 are supported".

I tried the same syntax with a planetary ephemeris file (de432s.bsp) and it works fine.

Can someone help me with that or knows any other ephemeris file for L2?

L2 file is here: https://naif.jpl.nasa.gov/pub/naif/generic_kernels/spk/lagrange_point/

Comment: A link to your `L2.bsp` file would be the minimum required information to replicate the error. You may get better results on the astronomy exchange.

Comment: You are right, thank you. Updated and posted there as well.